# C++ object referencing in classes

Tags: c++, class, reference, object-reference

I am wondering how to store a reference of an object inside of another object, and also set that reference as a private property. Example (pseudo-code):

```
class foo
{
    public:
        int size;
        foo( int );
};

foo::foo( int s ) : size( s ) {}

class bar
{
    public:
        bar( foo& );
    private:
        foo fooreference;
};

bar::bar( foo & reference )
{
    fooreference = reference;
}

foo firstclass( 1 );
bar secondclass( firstclass );
```

As you may be able to see, I just want to be able to store the reference of foo inside this bar class. I know how to simply bring it into a method and use it just in the scope of that method, but here I want to set it as a private property. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you define and use *any* class member.

Make sure you *initialise* the reference member with the _member-initialiser, instead of just assigning to it after-the-fact in the constructor body; recall that references must be initialised and cannot later be rebound.

```
class foo
{
    public:
        int size;
        foo( int );
};

foo::foo( int s ) : size( s ) {}

class bar
{
    public:
        bar(foo&);
    private:
        foo& fooreference;
};

bar::bar(foo& reference) : fooreference(reference)
{}

foo firstclass(1);
bar secondclass(firstclass);
```

Comment: does it have to be done in the constructor or can I have a separate method for this?

Comment: @Headspin: Constructor. *All* members are initialised during construction. Always. (That's what construction means!)

Comment: I guess this becomes a problem for me, as I need to initialize the bar class first, then later on, set the reference of foo.

Comment: @Headspin: You can't do that. If `fooreference` is a member of your `bar`, then it must be initialised as part of the `bar`'s initialisation. Perhaps consider a `shared_ptr<foo>` instead?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reseat a reference, so you have to set it in the initializer list.

```
struct Foo {};

struct Bar {
  Bar(Foo &foo_) : foo(foo_) {}
  void set(Foo &foo_) { foo = foo_; } // copies, doesn't reseat
  Foo &foo;
};
```

Comment: Actually, you wouldn't get an error from assigning one `Foo` to another `Foo`; you'd get one from omitting the initialisation, though.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Ah yea, my example isn't close to what I meant.  It would be a copy/assignment operation

Answer (score 1):

```
bar::bar( foo & reference )
{
    fooreference = reference;
}
```

`fooreference` is just another object. By assigning, you are making a copy of the reference. Note that `fooreference` isn't an alias to the `reference`.