# Pass global struct to a class as reference

Tags: c++, class, struct, pass-by-reference

I am trying to define a struct variable and use through classes as a sample below. I just want to assign struct variable once, not get/set in every function.

**global.h**

```
struct structPort{
  unsigned int portno;
  unsigned int timeleft;
  int dummy;
};

extern structPort mainPort; // this one is wanted to be used through classes
```

**class1.h**

```
#include "global.h"
class class1{

    structPort classPort;  // just wanted to deal with this inside class

    public:
        init(structPort &_prt);
        changeDummy();
}
```

**class1.cpp**

```
void class1::init(port &_prt){
    classPort = _prt;
}

void class1::changeDummy(){
    classPort.dummy = 20;
    cout << classPort.dummy << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"
#include "class1.h"

structPort mainPort;
class1 mainClass;

main(){

    mainPort.portno = 1;
    mainPort.dummy = 10;
    cout << mainPort.dummy << endl; 
    // this gives 10 - OK//   

    mainClass.init(mainPort);
    mainClass.changeDummy();
    // this gives 20 - OK//

    // reaching from the main again gives 10 - NOT OK
    // what i expected to see is 20
    cout << mainPort.dummy << endl;    
}
```

I think I could not find correct combination of reference and pointer.

Comment: Your `main` is missing the return type `int`. There is also `std::` missing before all `cout` and `endl`. Your member functions of `class1` are all missing return types in the class definition. Is there a reason you are using an `init` function, rather than the class constructor? `#include <iostream>` is also missing. To avoid giving you tipps in the wrong direction: Why do you need `mainClass` to hold a reference to `mainPort` instead of referring to `mainPort` directly or via copy?

Comment: code above is just a sample, i have just simplified that according to topic related, irrelevant lines have been deleted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ object referencing in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449813/c-object-referencing-in-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are copying the structport you have passed in, rather than storing a reference to it (and, in any case, a pointer is more appropriate here). In your `class1` definition you have this line:

```
structPort classPort;  // just wanted to deal with this inside class
```

Note how that's not a reference or a pointer, it's just a value, so this means that in init when you do this:

```
void class1::init(port &_prt){
    classPort = _prt;  // This copies prt to classPort, not a reference to it
}
```

It copies the values currently in `prt` to `classPort` and then when you modify it in `class1::changeDummy` it only changes the copy in `mainClass`, not the global object.

In order to achieve your goal, you need to change the definition of `class` in **class1.h** as follows:

```
class class1{

    structPort* classPort;

    public:
        init(structPort* _prt);
        changeDummy();
};
```

with a corresponding change to `structPort*` in the **class1.cpp** file, remembering it change to `classPort->dummy = 20;` from `classPort.dummy = 20;`. And then in your `main.cpp` file:

```
mainClass.init(&mainPort);
mainClass.changeDummy();
```

However, you do need to be careful with raw pointers in your code, and look into smart pointers for your future work.

Comment: you could be right, how can i assign that to pointer and use that as common in class1

Comment: @meakcey: I have added an explanation.